# When the control flow off the end of a function without a return, why there is still a returned value?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int func(int &a,int &b){
    if (a>b){
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(){
    int a=4,b=12;
    std::cout<<func(a,b)<<std::endl;
}
```

I think a run time error should occur because a is smaller than b, and the return statement is skipped. But it actually outputs the value of b no matter how I change the value of b. Could you please tell me why?

Comment: This is UB I suppose. You must be getting a warning "Not all code paths return a value".

Comment: Your compiler will give you a warning about this. If you tell your compiler to make all warnings errors (as a beginner this is a very good idea, as all warnings are logical errors in your thinking) then your code will fail to compile.

Comment: Your compiler **probably will** give you a warning about this. But there are cases that are hard for the compiler to diagnose, and if you're using multiple compilers you'll get in a battle where one compiler will warn you that that the code doesn't return a value, and when you add the return statement, another compiler will warn you that the newly added return statement can't be reached. That's why the behavior is undefined: it can't reliably be diagnosed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because a result of functions (if the return type is int) is transferred using `rax` register of CPU. `return` keyword places its argument in this register and returns to the caller function. But there is also an implicit `return` keyword at end of any function in C/C++ (if there is no explicit `return` placed by a programmer). And this is why this function returns control flow to the caller function.

But contents of `rax` register should be treated in this case as random because the compiler can use it for any variable or even totally ignore it.

**EDIT**: Because this is an accepted answer I should add important information here that was correctly mentioned in other answers and comments:

[eerorika](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53776881/3167374) and others say that omitting `return` in non-`void` function is UB (undefined behavior) and a compiler can do whatever it wants in this case. (I didn't fact-check this but I strongly believe it's true.)

[Klaus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53777107/3167374) added a helpful answer about compiler flags that aid one in detecting such UBs.

[Pete Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776838/when-the-control-flow-off-the-end-of-a-function-without-a-return-why-there-is-s#comment94414380_53776948) notes that there are many different CPU architectures with different registers. (One can even imagine a CPU without registers at all, for example, a fully stack-based CPU.)

<sub>But please note that my original answer was straight to the question, explaining what is going on. I think this has value. Yes, it's UB and yes, one better enables compiler warnings but we also can provide some explanations of what's really going on. It makes our understanding of programming and computers better.</sub>

Comment: That's not required. It's perfectly conforming to just start executing whatever occurs after that function in the binary image

Comment: Thank you! Actually the program outputs the value of b no matter how I change the value of b (as long as a<b). It seems to be related the value of b, why is that happening? Is the value of b transferred to rax register coincidentally?

Comment: Yes, but it is accidental: this time compiler decided to place `b` in `rax`, but next time with a different structure of the code or different compiler options, this can be another variable, f.ex. `a`, or no variable at all. And in the latter case the result can be even a value from some other part of the program. So as Kluas said in his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53777107/3167374 - it is UB.

Comment: Just a caution: there are many CPUs that don't have a register named `rax`. The principle here is correct: if there is no `return` statement you get whatever is in the location where the caller expected the result. +1.

Comment: This is incorrect. The behavior is undefined. This means that a compiler is free to generate literally **any** code for a program that contains this code.

Comment: *"I think this has value."* - It's the opposite: This is actively harmful. It sets the wrong expectation that reasoning about UB was meaningful or that the hardware had anything to do with this. Neither is true. Compilers are written under the assumption that UB never happens and will—by accident rather than malice—exploit any instance of UB. At that point, all bets are off. Mind you, this is happening long before the compiler has started emitting CPU instructions for any given ISA. The outcome is—quite literally—unpredictable, a point that cannot be stressed enough.

Answer (score 7):

> it should detect a run time error

That is not the case. The behaviour is undefined.

> It seems to be related the value of b, why is that happening?

Because the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 5):

Falling out of a non-`void` function without returning is undefined behaviour, there's nothing your program or the runtime "should" do in that case.

Answer (score 3):

You should not suppress the compiler warnings!

gcc says:

> main.cpp:35:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type].

As others already mentioned: Your program has UB! So read the warnings and fix your program accordingly!

> it should detect a run time error

And there is no need for run-time error, as the error is visible during compile-time! The core language has no run-time errors at all. If you see some error messages  during program execution, it is coming from library code like a called "terminate" from an exception or something else.

It is good to have all the warnings enabled and also sometimes helpful to run different compilers over the code to get most of warnings possible.

For gcc you could add:

```
-Wall -pedantic -Wextra
```

That enables a lot of warnings, but not all. There are still some warnings which are not addressed like: `-Wsuggest-override`

Answer (score 1):

In C++ if a function is declared to return a value but it doesn't, it is undefined behavior