# Recursive function c++ of type int return, steel works even if no return instruction is present on it's body

Tags: c++

The euclid function it's used for get the greatest common divisor of two number assuming the first number 
is greatest than the second.
euclid function is defined to return a int value. Even if in it's body no return instruction is present this function works correctly in C++. (Also can you check online: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler).
Why i have this behavior. I'm waiting to have a compiler error or to receive an unexpected value.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int euclid(int a,int b)
{
    if(b==0)
        b=a;
    else
        euclid(b,a%b);
}
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    a=20;
    b=5;
    cout<<"cmmdc dintre a si b este: "<<euclid(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The behaviour of your program is undefined. That's all there is to say really.

Comment: Most decent compiler should present warnings for this, at least with enough warnings enabled. Which is why you should always build with verbose warnings, and really treat them as errors.

Comment: If you use a return value from a function when it doesn't actually return a value then your program has [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Crashing, producing the wrong results and producing the right results all count as undefined behaviour.

Comment: "works correctly in C++" ... there is a difference between "appears to work with one particular compiler on one particular machine on one particular day when the moon is in a certain phase" and "works always" aka "is valid C++". Yours is the first ;)

Comment: This is a great learning opportunity to learn about how C and C++ handle undefined behaviour and let you shoot yourself in the foot if you want to do that.

Comment: It’s not that the program works correctly; it doesn’t.  It’s that the symptoms of its incorrect behavior are not easily recognizable on the particular machine you are running it on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When the control flow off the end of a function without a return, why there is still a returned value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776838/when-the-control-flow-off-the-end-of-a-function-without-a-return-why-there-is-s)